# Why does any RAM I put in my PC read as bad?

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building, post

I've been building computers for 15+ years and this one has been 10x more trouble than anything I've ever seen.  I'm on my 2nd motherboard now, and 3rd set of RAM, and I can't get a booting system.  I've been at it for a month (with most of that time spent waiting for new parts).

I'm currently using the [ASUS ROG STRIX B650E-F GAMING WiFi Socket AM5 (LGA 1718) Ryzen 7000 gaming motherboard](https://www.newegg.com/asus-rog-strix-b650e-f-gaming/p/N82E16813119604?Item=N82E16813119604) with [CORSAIR Dominator Platinum RGB 64GB (2 x 32GB) 288-Pin PC RAM DDR5 5200 (PC5 41600) Desktop Memory Model CMT64GX5M2B5200C40](https://www.newegg.com/corsair-64gb-288-pin-ddr5-sdram/p/N82E16820236840?Item=N82E16820236840).  I verified on the [asus website](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b650e-f-gaming-wifi-model/helpdesk_qvl_memory/) that the RAM is specifically supported.

But when I power on the system, it fails to post and the DRAM error LED on the motherboard is lit.  That's all I have to go on.  I tried each RAM module separately in case one was bad, but neither worked individually.

I have no idea what to do.  Send everything back and get a 3rd set of RAM and Motherboard?  This is so frustrating.

Comment: so, its possible its a powersupply or CPU issue. is your power supply completely compatible with your Mobo (do all power connectors on the board have all pins plugged in for all sockets?) have you tried it in a different room with a different wall socket? if not, then I would lean toward CPU. its difficult to separate RAM problems from Mobo problems, but its very difficult to separate CPU issues from Mobo/RAM. either something you haven't replaced is bad, or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Remove the ram and see what the POST does

Comment: Are you taking proper esd precautions? And no, touching metal momentarily occasionally does not count.

Comment: @FrankThomas Is it possible a CPU issue could light the DRAM LED on the motherboard?

Comment: @RohitGupta Same things happens with no RAM.  DRAM LED turns on.  System doesn't POST.

Comment: @Bib No I did not.

Comment: I would suspect the power supply next.  Ensure all the cables that the motherboard manual wants are connected and no more.  I had the issue when I replaced my motherboard, I plugged in all the power supply connectors and it would not boot.  When I removed the one that was not connected on the old motherboard, it sprung to life.

Comment: @xAptive - Yes; It’s possible

Comment: This happened once in my case, yours may not be the same case though. My newly built system would not POST. I tried cleaning the RAM slots with IPA cleaner and re-seated the RAM a few times and it came back to life.

Comment: Since the memory controller is part of the CPU, it could be a defective CPU - i.e. the only "main" component that has not been "replaced" - and the only component you haven't described - I'd also inspect the CPU socket for bent *pins*, though, since you've had multiple motherboards, that seems unlikely - check the CPU itself for any issues with the pads

Comment: I've seen a bent pin on the cpu cause this.  Or cascade failure -- broken dimm bends the pin in the socket when you insert it.  Next dimm you put in the socket is damaged by the bent pin...  or just dirt as already suggested.

Comment: @user10489 - Ryzen 7000 CPUs have no pins :p